# Can we use the ABPeoplePicker view for something other than selecting a single contact?

Tags: iphone

I'm attempting to implement a 'better' address book for IPhone and I just want to make additions to Apple's current address book interface. Do I have to re-implement everything from scratch (contacts divided by letter headers, all alphabet buttons on the right, and so on) or is there a way I can somehow use and modify the PeoplePicker view?

(I'm still pretty new to the IPhone SDK, feel free to ask any questions that will help elaborate my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Oreilly's ["iPhone SDK Application Development" book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154059/)

here is a more detailed answer of:

> Well, with UITableView you can do
>   pretty much 100% what the regular
>   "select a contact from a list" part of
>   the addressbook does and then build
>   upon that.

You basically have to implement sections and the index bar methods for a UITableView. (based on my shallow reading) the following methods need to be implemented:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { 

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection (NSInteger)section

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSection IndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger) index
```

Comment: you may want to look at some of the iPhone samples in the SDK, particularly the timezone ones. They demonstrate all this and more.

Comment: cool - thanks for the help and info so far Andrew

geez you're up late hehe

Answer (score 2):

Well, with UITableView you can do pretty much 100% what the regular "select a contact from a list" part of the addressbook does and then build upon that.

Comment: not yet - my question is basically asking if I have to reinvent it. I guess it's just my personal preference that I don't do any extra work that's not required. Since time is a valued commodity and I'd rather spend it on stuff that counts.

If I don't have a choice, that's fine too; just not ideal.

Comment: My point is that TableView is already 90% of the wheel (headers, sections etc). If you want an exact copy, how is that a "better" address book?

Comment: I guess I'm just lazy; much appreciated for the reply